# Why do I need binstubs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I don't completely understand the purpose of binstubs feature in Rails.

For example, when I ran `bin/bundle binstubs rspec-rails` I got the following output:

```
rspec-rails has no executables, but you may want one from a gem it depends on.
  railties has: rails
  rspec-core has: autospec, rspec
```

What does it mean? And why do I need `bin/bundle binstubs rspec-core` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Binstubs are wrapper scripts around executables** (sometimes referred to
> as "binaries", although they don't have to be compiled) **whose purpose
> is to prepare the environment before dispatching the call to the
> original executable.**
>
> In the Ruby world, the most common binstubs are the ones that RubyGems
> generates after installing a gem that contains executables. But
> binstubs can be written in any language, and it often makes sense to
> create them manually.

Source: [rbenv wiki – Understanding binstubs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs)

Comment: Good answer what they are, but why do we need them? If I can run just `rails` why do I need `bin/rails`?